# AutoSize Excel Chart DataLabel to fit Height of Text in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, scatter-plot

I have a scatter chart created using VBA which displays perfectly except for I'm trying to find a work with the text of the data label to accomplish two things:

1. Wrap the data label text to multiple lines so that labels with lengthy text do not overlap other.
2. Adjust the Height of the DataLabel to the height of the wrapped text

Here is my vba snippet code for attempting to accomplish this:

```
scatterSeries.Points(i).DataLabel.Format.TextFrame2.AutoSize = msoAutoSizeShapeToFitText
scatterSeries.Points(i).DataLabel.Format.TextFrame2.WordWrap = msoTrue
scatterSeries.Points(i).DataLabel.Width = 60
```

In the first line of code I am attempting to size the shape to fit the text which also allows the text to overflow the size of the shape. This is needed when I have lengthy data labels.

In the second line of code, this does not appear to affect anything, but I was hoping this could work to help me resolve my issue but it does not and does not seem from what i have noticed to affect or change anything.

In the last line of code, this is an important one as I want to control the width that a label can take up on the chart to avoid overlap on the x-axis, so I set the width to 60 with the hope that by autosizing i can work more vertically by allowing labels with lengthy text to be displayed on multiple lines (which seems to work).

What I cannot seem to do simply is get the data label shape aka 'text box' to autosize so that it expands to the height of the full data label when written on multiple lines. This is important because users may need to select the label on the chart and it becomes difficult to select if the height is not the size of the full label text.

An example is below of how it is behaving currently.

[image]

Comment: I cannot understand in which direction the label becomes problematic. Your picture is not of too much help. On its width or on its height? If on its height (like it looks in the picture),  `.WordWrap = msoTrue` does not help together with `.AutoSize = msoAutoSizeShapeToFitText`.  `WordWrap` should be `msoFalse`. And **you should set the shape height** `.DataLabel.Height`, to limit the (calculated/default) height increasing.

Comment: Thanks for the comment this helps. And your assumption is correct, it is problematic on it's Height.

Here is what i have now:
scatterSeries.Points(i).DataLabel.Format.TextFrame2.WordWrap = msoFalse
scatterSeries.Points(i).DataLabel.Width = 60
scatterSeries.Points(i).DataLabel.Height = 60
scatterSeries.Points(i).DataLabel.Format.TextFrame2.AutoSize = msoAutoSizeShapeToFitText

This still does not work. using the code above it plots the data label horizontally and does not display on multiple lines as I need it to

Any other thoughts on what I might be doing wrong here.

Comment: Are there width limitations, too? If not, i would not set the width. At least, do it for the testing sake. It maybe reaches a minimum font size with all that conditions...

Comment: The idea is to limit the label width so that labels with lengthy text do not overlap other plotted values.  My hope is to limit the width, but allow the label to be displayed on multiple lines as I will have more vertical space to play with than horizontal space which is why the width is limited. Per your recommendation, i did remove the width limitation and the result does not change.

Comment: I just wasted five minutes looking for a way to autofit the height of the label. Apparently there is no way to do so. `.AutoSize` only works on the width of the label/